# Why doesn't synthetic element click work?

Tags: javascript, dom, automation

I'm working on an automation tool. A chrome extension finds an element via some selector and then clicks on it. Usually it works fine, but in at least one case where the element is part of a react select component, the element is correctly identified, but the synthetic click does nothing - i.e., the select drop down does not appear.

One possibility - that the javascript which sets the click handler has not completed - can be ruled out. The behaviour is the same even if the page has been loaded for some time before I trigger the click.

I am not including code here as the relevant bit is super simple. I definitely have the element and I definitely called click() on it. The question is, what might cause a synthetic click to behave differently from a real mouse click?

Comment: <select> are kind of tied to the OS, browsers don't give a lot of freedom in this area and will indeed ignore synthetic clicks on these (well they at least won't trigger the default behavior...).

Comment: @Kaiido you're making my day! Please make this an answer so I can upvote it, not that you need 10 more rep... :)

Comment: No I don't, and I'd love to see someone make me wrong on this. I'll dig a bit more if I can.

Comment: @Kaiido, actually if I knew this problem definitely only applied to Select, I could use the JS element.click method call on everything else, and fall back to X11 clicks if the element is a select, which would be nice.